# Linker fails due to duplicate symbol

Tags: c++, c++11, struct

Using the code below, when I try to compile

```
clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -o test sales_function.cpp sales_prog.cpp
```

I get the following error

```
duplicate symbol __ZN10Sales_data7combineERKS_ in:
/var/folders/7f/9r4z5bs90bjfm3dy1k_g03xc0000gn/T/sales_functions-5G1FRA.o
/var/folders/7f/9r4z5bs90bjfm3dy1k_g03xc0000gn/T/sales_prog-82wDRv.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Now to get the non member functions in the file sales_functions.cpp to work, I included the "sales_dat.h" header since struct Sales_data that the functions uses is defined there. In that file though, I have the non member function 'read', that is called in one of the constructors of the struct Sales_data. So to circumvent that I forward declared struct and declared the read function before the struct definition in sales_dat.h.

I've been trying different things like putting the definition of struct in it's own file and putting the declaration only in the header file. But that gave me other problems where the compiler couldn't use it's objects in my non member function file.

That error I get, but I don't understand why I get the above error. I'm thinking maybe it has something to do with "sales_dat.h" header being in both sales_prog.cpp and sales_function.cpp but it seems like I had to put it in sales_function.cpp in order for the non member function to use the struct Sales_data objects.

What exactly is going on here?
sales_functions.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "sales_dat.h"
std::istream &read(std::istream &is, Sales_data &item)
{
    double price = 0;
    is >> item.bookName >> item.books_sold >> price;
    item.revenue = price * item.books_sold;
    return is;
}
std::ostream &print(std::ostream &os, Sales_data &item)
{
    os << item.isbn() << " " << item.books_sold << " " << item.revenue;
    return os;
}
Sales_data add(const Sales_data &lhs, const Sales_data &rhs)
{
    Sales_data sum = lhs;
    sum.combine(rhs);
    return sum;
}
```

sales_dat.h

```
#ifndef SALES_DAT_H
#define SALES_DAT_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
struct Sales_data;
std::istream &read(std::istream &, Sales_data &);
struct Sales_data {
    std::string bookName;
    std::string isbn() const { return bookName; }
    Sales_data &combine(const Sales_data &);
    unsigned books_available = 10;
    unsigned books_sold = 0;
    double revenue = 0;
    unsigned total_sold = 0;
    unsigned count = 1;
    Sales_data() = default;
    Sales_data(unsigned c) : count(c) {}
    Sales_data(const std::string &s) : bookName(s) {}
    Sales_data(const std::string &s, unsigned m, unsigned n, double p) : bookName(s), books_sold(m), books_available(n), revenue(p*m) {}
    Sales_data(std::istream &inpst) { read(inpst, *this); }
};
std::ostream &print(std::ostream &, Sales_data &);
Sales_data add(const Sales_data &, const Sales_data &);
Sales_data &Sales_data::combine(const Sales_data &rs)
{
    count += rs.count;
    books_sold += rs.books_sold;
    revenue += rs.revenue;
    return *this;
}
#endif
```

sales_prog.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "sales_dat.h"
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Enter a transaction" << std::endl;
    Sales_data total(std::cin);
    if(std::cin) {
        Sales_data trans;
        while(read(std::cin,trans)) {
            if(total.isbn() == trans.isbn()) {
                total = add(total,trans);
            }
            else {
                std::cout << "Number of " << total.isbn() << " transactions: " << total.count << std::endl;
                std::cout << "Number of " << total.isbn() << " sold: " << total.books_sold << std::endl;
                std::cout << "Revenue: " << total.revenue << std::endl;
                total = trans;
            }
        }
        if(total.books_sold != 0) {
            std::cout << "Number of " << total.isbn() << " transactions: " << total.count << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Number of " << total.isbn() << " sold: " << total.books_sold << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Revenue: " << total.revenue << std::endl;
        }
        else
            std::cout << "Entry: " << total.isbn() << " has zero sold" << std::endl;
    }
    else
        std::cerr << "No transaction" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: According to http://pear.warosu.org/c++filtjs/ `_ZN10Sales_data7combineERKS_` is the mangled name for `Sales_data::combine(Sales_data const&)`. Is there any reason you put the _definition_ of `Sales_data::combine` in the header (sales_dat.h) instead of the implementation file (sales_functions.cpp)? (If not, you can just move it there; else you can make it `inline` as suggested by Joachim Pileborg)

Comment: combine is a member function for the class so I put it in the header file where the class is also defined.

Comment: Nothing requires that. And the usual convention is to separate the member function definitions from their declarations (i.e. from the class definition). _Edit:_ More clearly: usually, in the header file you put the class definition (which contains the declarations of the member functions, some of which can be directly defined like your `isbn()`), and in the source file you put the definitions of the member functions.

Comment: I see. So I can define member function in my sales_function.cpp source file also. In that case I would not need to make it inline.

Comment: Wow answered both questions in one post. Excellent!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Sales_data::combine` function is defined inside the header file, but you're not making it `inline` so each source file including that header file defines the function.

Comment: Inline uses the the function code instead of calling the function correct? Isn't a function defined inside a class automatically inline? If so if it is declared inside the class and defined outside, does it lose this feature?

Comment: @Comrade The `inline` keyword is just a *hint*. It may (or may not) cause the compiler to inline the function when called. And yes, if you define a function *in* the class it's automatically marked `inline`. But you don't define the function in the class, but outside the class.

Comment: Agreed. I declared it but defined it outside which was the problem. Not the same thing!

Comment: Yes I meant I declared inside the class and defined it outside.

Comment: @Comrade That's what I meant when I said you define it in the header file. That makes it defined in all translation units including the header file.

Comment: One last question. Should the class be defined in the same file as the header or should I put it in a different file? I was running into a whole host of other issues when I tried to put the class definition in a source file and just it's declaration in the header.

Comment: @Comrade The class must be defined in each source file using it, so that should be like it is in the header file. It's the functions in the class that can't be defined the way you did in your question.

Comment: What I meant was could I put the class definition in the sales_function.cpp file and just have the declaration in the sales_dat.h file? Or could I even put the class definition in a separate file of it's own separate from the sales_function.cpp or sales_dat.h file and have the declaration in the sales_dat.h file?

Comment: @Comrade No, because then the other sources using the class wouldn't know anything more than that there is a class called `Sales_data`, but they wouldn't know methods or anything else and so can't really use the class.

Comment: @Comrade - The `inline` keyword has multiple meanings. One is a *hint* to the compiler that you would prefer the function to be expanded in line, wherever it is called. The other meaning is that an out-of-line member function definition such as your `Sales_data::combine` is to be treated as if it were defined in-line, that is, inside the class definition. You absolutely need to use `inline` in this latter sense if a function is defined in a header and the header is included in multiple source files lest you fall prey to the one definition rule.

Comment: @DavidHammen. When I use inline, it will still be defined initially correct? But subsequent occurrences of function definition, the compiler would use the hint to just expand the code and not define it.

Comment: @Comrade - Even with that `inline` keyword, most compilers will generate code for the function for each compiled source file in which the function is used. What `inline` does is to make linker (arbitrarily) use only one of those duplicate definitions as the sole definition of the function; the others are discarded. This means all of those multiple compiled meanings had better be true duplicates. It's *undefined behavior* if they are not duplicates. The compiler and linker can be, and typically are, quiet when you violate this aspect of the ODR.